# Step into steps over Visual Studio debugger SQL Server T-SQL code

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, debugging

Since Microsoft Deprecated the debug functionality for SSMS, I am using Visual Studio to debug my stored procedure.

It was working fine before, and all of the sudden, after a few updates to my stored procedure, I am no longer able to step into the stored procedure. Stepping into, steps over... I've hit a wall...

The way I got this screen was by right clicking on my SP and picking "Debug stored procedure"...  I can't step into it at line 7. It always steps over.  Allow SQL\CLR debugging is ON, as shown.

Does anybody know an easy way to debug SQL Server code? I am almost tempted to use the earlier version of SSMS, but I try not to, because I am forward-thinking and they deprecated it for a reason, but almost seems like it was working better through SQL Server itself. See screenshot.

[image: Picture]

Comment: The deprecated version is the best.  So much easier to debug.  That is the only way I could get it to work easily.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to happens when there is some sort of declaration problem within the function called.  So, I had a type definition, but the name of the type definition changed.  The code, all of the sudden, steps over instead of into.

Not very easy to crack.  I recommend using older version....